# Can I do a software that search on google?

Tags: php, web-services

Hello
Are there any APIs to search on Google web?
I would like to set the nation like (IT, US, CA etc etc) and do a search on it.

Let me know, thank you

Comment: This is like the first result if you do a "Google search" yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the search API

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?hl=$lang&q=$query")
```

Comment: Wrong way. There's an API, you should use it. Here you rely on an url that *might* change.

Comment: I was joking. Also, the API _might_ change too!

Comment: Oh ok, that was not obvious though ;) (well to me at least :p)

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

Took me 15 seconds in Google to find.

Note: If you plan on using more that 100 queries in a day, you will need to pay for the service.

edit: It should be noted this is for creating a custom search engine for your site. If you just want it to run a search across the web on Google... There are widgets out there for that. I'll assume the former even though both can be answered in less than a minute using Google.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  Take a look at http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

> The JSON/Atom Custom Search API lets you develop websites and programs to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically. With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get search results in either JSON or Atom format.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [CURL](http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-init.php) extension. Allows requests and interesting parameters (support faster gzipped requests on-the-fly, for example):

```
$lang = 'es'; // Spanish language
$query = 'answer to life, the universe and everything'; // query request

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?hl=$lang&q=$query");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate"); // return compress content
$content = curl_exec($ch); // execute request and save in $content var
curl_close($ch); // close and free
```